# I want to edit the datagridview to Update Dataset directly to DB,but always failed

Tags: c#, datagridview

My Problem as follows;

Last row of `datagridview` is always Focused, so when I click the `btnSave` of `toolStripButton`, I can not save the last row data to the database. How should I solve this problem? I know if I use the Button Control, I can solve this problem. But I want to know more:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                dgvHead.EndEdit();
                dgvHead.RefreshEdit();
                dgvHead.Refresh();
                dgvHead.Update();
                dgvHead.LostFocus += new EventHandler(dataGridView1_LostFocus);
                //dgvHead.ClearSelection();


            //int id = 0;
            //保存到数据库之前先判断一下主表是否有重复记录
            string fno = txtfNo.Text.Trim();
            string fname = txtPname.Text.Trim();
            int orderqty = Convert.ToInt32(txtOrderQty.Text);
            double orderc = Convert.ToDouble(txtOrderCoefficient.Text);
            Image pic = pbchef.Image;
            //主表的修改
            string sql1 = "select count(1) from desProductAttach where fno='" + fno + "' and fno!='" + args["pNo"].ToString() + "' and fname='" + fname + "' and orderqty=" + orderqty + " and orderCoefficient=" + orderc + "";
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(SqlHelp.GetValue(CommandType.Text, sql1));
            if (count != 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("数据库中已经存在重复记录,请修改后重新录入!");
                return;
            }
            string sql2 = @"update desProductAttach set fno='" + fno + "',fname='" + fname + "',orderqty=" + orderqty + ",orderCoefficient=" + orderc + " where id="+id+"";
            SqlHelp.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.Text,sql2);

           //子表的更新(通过数据源更新)
            if (ds1.HasChanges())
            {
                SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda1);
                sda1.Update(ds1.Tables[0]);
                ds1.AcceptChanges();
               // dgvHead.Update();
                MessageBox.Show("保存成功");
               // ischange = false;
            }

        }
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: show some code to help you better !

Comment: should post code of what you are doing. Focus in general can't hinder with db operations.

Comment: @wqvincent post the code..then we can help..

Comment: i have already post the save_button code,this is not a common button, this is a toolStripButton